# ImportError: cannot import name 'Font' from partially initialized module 'pygame.font' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm on my Mac M1 playing around with Pygame. What happening is that Pygame isn't allowing me to use the font module. Looking at some GitHub discussions I've tried installing sdl2 libraries using brew but nothing works. How would I resolve this problem?

P.S Although there is no error with the code I will provide it anyways.

```py
import pygame
from pygame.draw import circle,rect
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.font import SysFont
import random
pygame.init()

width = 500
height = 900
font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial',50)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
players = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
plasers = pygame.sprite.Group()
alasers = pygame.sprite.Group()
ENEMYLASER = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.time.set_timer(ENEMYLASER,1000)
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player,self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((30,40))
        self.surf.fill((255,0,0))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.speed = 5
        self.rect.center = (width//2,800)
    def update(self,pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_a]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed,0)
        if pressed_keys[K_d]:
            self.rect.move_ip(self.speed,0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(self.speed,0)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed,0)
        if self.rect.right >width:
            self.rect.right = width
        if self.rect.left<0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self,alasers):
            players.remove(self)
            all_sprites.remove(self)
            self.kill()
        
class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super(Alien,self).__init__()
        self.surf=pygame.Surface((50,50))
        
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.rect.center=(x,y)
        self.surf.fill((0,255,0))
    def update(self):
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self,plasers):
            enemies.remove(self)
            all_sprites.remove(self)
            self.kill()
class PLaser(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super(PLaser,self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((10,20))
        self.surf.fill((0,0,255))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.rect.center=(x,y)
        self.speed = -5
        self.visibility = True
    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(0,self.speed)
        if not self.visibility:
            plasers.remove(self)
            all_sprites.remove(self)
            self.kill()
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self,enemies):
            
            self.visibility= False
class ALaser(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super(ALaser,self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((10,20))
        self.surf.fill((255,255,0))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.rect.center=(x,y)
        self.speed = 5
        self.visibility = True
    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(0,self.speed)
        if not self.visibility:
            alasers.remove(self)
            all_sprites.remove(self)
            self.kill()
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self,players):
            
            self.visibility= False

        
player = Player()


players.add(player)
all_sprites.add(player)
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        alien = Alien(x*100+100,y*100+100)
        enemies.add(alien)
        all_sprites.add(alien)
def won():
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
        text = font.render("You won",True,(255,0,0))
        text_rect = text.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = (width//2,height//2)
        screen.blit(text,text_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
def lost():
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
        text = font.render("You lost",True,(255,0,0))
        text_rect = text.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = (width//2,height//2)
        screen.blit(text,text_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        

running=True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running=False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                laser = PLaser(player.rect.centerx,player.rect.centery)
                plasers.add(laser)
                all_sprites.add(laser)
        if event.type == ENEMYLASER:
            enemy = random.choice(enemies.sprites())
            laser= ALaser(enemy.rect.centerx,enemy.rect.centery)
            alasers.add(laser)
            all_sprites.add(laser)
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pressed_keys= pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)
    for entity in plasers:
        entity.update()
    for entity in alasers:
        entity.update()
    for entity in enemies:
        entity.update()
    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf,entity.rect)
    if len(players.sprites()) == 0:
        running=False
        lost()
    if len(enemies.sprites()) == 0:
        running=False
        won()
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please show the traceback. Without it, it's hard to pin down the circular import that you need to fix. And please understand that a circular import *is* an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is fixed in the current pygame main on Github, through this pull request: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2636.

Here's what you should do:

- clone the pygame repository locally, navigate to it.
- `brew install sdl2 sdl2_gfx sdl2_image sdl2_mixer sdl2_net sdl2_ttf`
- `brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz`
- `pip3 install .`