# The Pygame Mixer module is not available

Tags: python, pip, pygame

Even in a blank program if I type the line of code,

```
 pygame.mixer.init()
```

PyCharm throws the error,

```
 NotImplementedError: mixer module not available (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.mixer')
```

My computer is running macOS Big Sur 11.4, and pycharm is running python 3.9
The version of pip that my computer says it has installed is 21.1.3

If anyone knows how to reinstall pip quickly or if there is some software I am missing in my computer the help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you named a script of your own `pygame.py`, by any chance?  That would be picked up by `import` instead of the installed module.

Comment: Try installing the latest GitHub version from source, I think this is an M1 pygame error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68614138/13816541

Comment: have you run `pip install pygame`   what version does `pip show pygame` show

Answer (score 2):

in pycharm, to use some modules you need to install them independently . in order to install the module
open pycharm, in Pycharm select the following path

```
File >> Settings. Project >> Project Interpreter >>
```

and at the right you will find a **'+'** icon click on that, and search for Pygame, you will find a install button below click that. after the installation you are good to go.

to use **pygame.mixer** module try the code below

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
"""
Your code goes here
"""
```